# Distributed Rate limiting using SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, rate-limiting

I have a use-case which requires to consume messages from a Queue with 100s of lambda consumers. But the constraint is that the consumption needs to happen at no more than x TPS, because we are dependent on a downstream service which will shed the extra load. Is it possible to do such thing with SQS?

Comment: Set a concurrency limit with Lambda

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.